# Laravel post 302 redirection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have five Laravel applications which are running in Windows, Apache2 server. Those applications are developed in Laravel 5.2.43. The new application is developed in Laravel 5.5.46.

After migrating new applications into the same server, I am facing following issue.

**New application issue (Laravel 5.5.46)**

After migrating the new application to the same server, I am getting 302 redirections when I submit the form in normal submission as well as AJAX call.  `csrf_token` is field available in the form.

**Existing application issue (Laravel 5.2.43)**

Existing application searching tables in the new application database.

I am not using `php artisan serve`.  All the applications are running like http://host/project/public

Please help me.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $regsiteredVehicleDetails = TestVehicle::updateOrCreate(
        ['vehicle_type_id' => $request->vehicle_type_id,
        'registration_no' => $request->registration_no,
        'model_name' => $request->model_name,
        'engine_no' => $request->engine_no,
        'vehicle_identification_number' => $request->vehicle_identification_number
        ], 
        ['status' => $databaseStatusActive,
         'customer_id'=>null,
        'comments' => $comments]
    );

    if ($regsiteredVehicleDetails->id) {
        Session::flash('message', 'Test Vehicle is registered successfully!..'); 
        Session::flash('status', 'success');
    } else {
        Session::flash('message', 'Something went wrong....!');
        Session::flash('unicode', 'Unicode is not generated');
        Session::flash('status', 'failure');
    }
    return redirect('tvr');
}
```

Comment: can you show the form submission code and corresponding code in the controller?

Comment: Form Submission:
$('#customer_form').submit(function (){
        if ($("#vehicle_identification_number").val() == "") {
                $(".modal-body").html("<p class='error'>Please enter VIN</p>");
                $('#popup_div').modal('show');
                return false;
            }else {
    return true;
            }
});

Comment: @Saly3301  I have updated controller method

Comment: can you `dd('reached');` in the first line of the store method to check that the redirect is not happening somewhere else?

Comment: @Saly3301  after adding that also redirect is happening

Comment: On a sidenote: `http://host/project/public` The `/public` folder in your project should be the `DocumentRoot` of your VirtualHost

Comment: @kerbholz it is in htdocs folder

Comment: I don't see what the issue is `redirect('tvr')` is a 302 redirect.

Comment: Please add your javascript, route and any other code into your question so someone can assist.

Comment: @designtocode if i put die() in the method, then also redirecting to home page

Comment: Ok @Ulaganathan please add your route and javascript code to the question.